# How to fix: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory 'src/node_modules/native-base/Fonts'

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I was following up a tutorial which used expo and needed the fonts for native code, but I'm not using expo thus I don't need those fonts. I removed the code that was using them (nothing that would affect the other parts of the app), and now it gives me this hideous error that it says is located on my source folder "src/navigation/node_modules/native-base/Fonts", the node modules are not even located on the src.

Bear in mind that I'm new to react native, any help would be appreciated.

**Terminal output:**

> bundling failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir
>   '/Users/relativity/Documents/ReactNative-Projects/test/src/navigation/node_modules/native-base/Fonts'

Comment: found what the problem is yet?

Answer (score 0):

Try npm install in your project directory, perhaps you deleted something that wasn't meant to be deleted.
Open terminal and navigate to your project directory and run `npm install` after it is done run `react-native run-android` or `react-native run-ios` 
It looks like some default fonts are missing.

Answer (score 0):

npm rebuild native-base is the official solution. Deleting your node_modules and running npm install will also do the trick. If this doesn't work try clearing cache, deleting node_modules and installing packages.

Comment: Thanks for your answer kate, but same output... I really don't understand this error. If I encounter a solution I will post it as well